# Using javascript from typescript, bundling using webpack. Runtime errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a dead simple javascript function:

```
function alphanum(a, b) {
  function chunkify(t) {
    var tz = [], x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

    while (i = (j = t.charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
      var m = (i == 46 || (i >=48 && i <= 57));
      if (m !== n) {
        tz[++y] = "";
        n = m;
      }
      tz[y] += j;
    }
    return tz;
  }

  var aa = chunkify(a);
  var bb = chunkify(b);

  for (x = 0; aa[x] && bb[x]; x++) {
    if (aa[x] !== bb[x]) {
      var c = Number(aa[x]), d = Number(bb[x]);
      if (c == aa[x] && d == bb[x]) {
        return c - d;
      } else return (aa[x] > bb[x]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  }
  return aa.length - bb.length;
}
```

This is in alphanum.js.

I want to use it in a typescript file.  So I have done the following:

```
declare function alphanum(param1: any, param2: any): number;
require("./../utils/alphanum.js");
```

I am using webpack to bundle everything together.  This seems fine, no errors, no problems.

When I try to use the function I get errors on the client:

```
EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: alphanum is not defined
```

I feel like I am missing something really obvious. Am I doing anything wrong with webpack and requires?

Edit:

Here's my webpack config:

webpack.common.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
    root: [
      helpers.root('./src'),
      helpers.root('node_modules')
    ],
     alias: {
      // bind version of jquery-ui
      "jquery.ui.core": "jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js",     
      "jquery.ui.widget": "jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"
     }
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      "window.jQuery":"jquery"})
  ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  debug: true,

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors":true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

It's an Angular2 app, if that helps, webpack config came mostly from: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ReferenceError: alphanum is not defined

By default with webpack each file is consider a *module*. You are using it as a `global`.

## Fix

If you still want it global you would:

```
function alphanum(a, b) {
  function chunkify(t) {
    var tz = [], x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

    while (i = (j = t.charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
      var m = (i == 46 || (i >=48 && i <= 57));
      if (m !== n) {
        tz[++y] = "";
        n = m;
      }
      tz[y] += j;
    }
    return tz;
  }

  var aa = chunkify(a);
  var bb = chunkify(b);

  for (x = 0; aa[x] && bb[x]; x++) {
    if (aa[x] !== bb[x]) {
      var c = Number(aa[x]), d = Number(bb[x]);
      if (c == aa[x] && d == bb[x]) {
        return c - d;
      } else return (aa[x] > bb[x]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  }
  return aa.length - bb.length;
}

// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
global.alphanum = alphanum;
```

Comment: But why he's getting error in the browser for export key word?

Comment: Yes, this seems better! And do you know the syntax to keep it as a module?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to export your function from alphanum.js that's why it is undefined.

```
export function alphanum(a, b) {
```

from your alphanum.js and it should work.

Comment: It doesn't like it "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"

Comment: tha't prebebly it's not compiling. browser don't understand export so you need to set webpack to resolve js files  resolve: {
             extensions: ["", ".ts", ".js"]
         }
[please read this also this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions)

Comment: I have that.  Webpack is putting the function (with the export) in the bundle. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Are you targeting es6. Export is not supported yet in browser with es6

Comment: Please share your webpack config and tsconfig. Are you getting this error in browser?

Comment: I have a similar seed in my repo and everything look almost same beside the tsconfig  [here is the link of my repo ](https://github.com/ jorawarsingh/angular2-webpack-seed) is your app on github?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120723/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-dandan).